# why use invoke helper rather than just call functor?

Tags: c++, functor, c++17

As shown in the 'possible implementation' of [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply) we see that the standard library function [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) is used to invoke the callable object `F`.

Is it needed in this situation? if so, for what reason?

What are the benefits of writing:

```
template<typename F, typename ... Args>
decltype(auto) func(F &&f, Args &&... args){
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

over:

```
template<typename F, typename ... Args>
decltype(auto) func(F &&f, Args &&... args){
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pointer to member is `Callable`, and `invoke` (or `INVOKE`, as that [soon-to-be-seven-bullet-point construct](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2219) is known in the Standard)'s magic handles this case (well, four and soon to be six cases actually), while the function call syntax doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

I want to complement [T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31838711/2805305) with a syntactic example:

```
struct X {
  int x;
  int foo(int a) const { return a + x; }
};
```

and you have an `X` object and a pointer to a member function, e.g.:

```
X obj = X{1000};
auto fn = &X::foo;
```

and need to call `func`.

- With the call syntax, this won't work:

  ```
  func_call(fn, obj, 24); // compiler error
  ```

  > error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in [...]

  Instead you have to work around it:

  ```
  func_call([obj, fn](int a) { return (obj.*fn)(a); }, 24);
  ```
- If you had the invoke method, you could just have written:

  ```
  func_invoke(fn, obj, 24);
  ```